# expressionengine channel custom field to PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, expressionengine, custom-fields, channel

Is it possible to assign channel custom fields to PHP array var?

Something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="challenges" require_entry="yes" limit="1" cache="yes" refresh="60"}

{reverse_related_entries id="week_stats"}
<?php
$i = 1;
$stats[$i]['fat'] = "{body_fat}";
$stats[$i]['weight'] = "{weight}";
$stats[$i]['biceps'] = "{bicep_left}";
$stats[$i]['chest'] = "{chest}";
$stats[$i]['thigh'] = "{thigh_left}"
$i++
?>

{/reverse_related_entries}
<?php print_r($stats);?>
...
...
...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Of course PHP template parsing should be ON (output). I tried this but cant get it work with array??

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could go/ are wrong here:

1) Since you're parsing on output if any tag data contains a quote '"' will break your PHP.

2) There's a semicolon missing after

```
$stats[$i]['thigh'] = "{thigh_left}"
```